# What is the difference between ImmutableJS Map() and fromJS()?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

```
var a = {address: {postcode: 5085}}

var b = Immutable.fromJS(a)
var c = b.setIn(['address', 'suburb'], 'broadview').toJS(); // no error
console.log(c); 

var d = Immutable.Map(a);
var e = d.setIn(['address', 'suburb'], 'broadview').toJS(); // error invalid keyPath(…)
```

Could someone explain the difference.

Thanks,

Answer (score 86):

In this example,

```
var a = {address: {postcode: 5085}}
var d = Immutable.Map(a);
```

Here, **`d.get('address')` is immutable**. It's value cannot change to any other objects. We can only create a new Object from the existing object using the `Immutable.Map.set()` function of ImmutableJS.

But, the **object referenced by `d.get('address')` i.e, `{postcode:5085}` is a standard JavaScript object. It is mutable**. A statement like this can alter the value of `postcode`:

```
d.get('address').postcode=6000;
```

If you check the value of d again, you can see that he value has been changed.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(d));   //Outputs {"address":{"postcode":6000}}
```

which is against the principles of immutability.

The reason is that ImmutableJS data structures like `List` and `Map` imparts the immutability feature to only the level-1 members of the `List`/`Map`.

So, **if you have objects inside arrays or arrays inside objects and want them too to be immutable, your choice is `Immutable.fromJS`**.

```
var a = {address: {postcode: 5085}}
var b = Immutable.fromJS(a);
b.get('address').postcode=6000;
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));   //Outputs {"address":{"postcode":5085}}
```

From the above example you can clearly know how `fromJS` makes the nested members immutable.

I hope you understood the difference between `Map` and `fromJS`. All the best =)

Comment: omg, thank you so much for explaining this! i've been struggling with this, and i finally understand why my map.get(k) was returning by reference (and how to avoid it without doing some kind of stupid deepCopy(map.get(k)).

Comment: Excellent! The Immutable.js Map docs aren't clear of this core difference to fromJS: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map

Answer (score 25):

`fromJS` does a deep conversion. That is, it'll recurse through all the keys and convert all elements to Lists, Maps, etc.

In your second example, `address` is a plain object, not an ImmutableJS object, so you cannot use `setIn` to change its value.